# Flutter set width of row

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I want my Row width fixed with some given value. But Row is taking full width.

I want as below;

[image]

But its taking full width as below:

[image]

What i have tried :

```
Card(
  child: Row(
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
    children: [
      Icon(Icons.height),
      SizedBox(
        width: 5,
      ),
      Text(
        'Sort',
        style: ReediusCustomTheme.lable1
            .copyWith(color: ReediusCustomTheme.lableColor1),
      ),
      SizedBox(
        width: 24,
      ),
      Text(
        '|',
        style: ReediusCustomTheme.lable1
            .copyWith(color: ReediusCustomTheme.lableColor1),
      ),
      SizedBox(
        width: 24,
      ),
      Icon(Icons.filter_alt_outlined),
      SizedBox(
        width: 5,
      ),
      Text(
        'Filter',
        style: ReediusCustomTheme.lable1
            .copyWith(color: ReediusCustomTheme.lableColor1),
      ),
    ],
  ),
),
```

Comment: Is your card inside a column that has `crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,`

Comment: Wrap your row in a sizedbox and give 50% of width to it.

Comment: @AbdallahA.Odeh Its in ListView

Comment: It's related to Card parent widget 
try Wrap Card widget with Center

Answer (score 2):

It depends on what your Card is inside of - e.g. with just your code wrapping the Card in e.g. a Center, or Container give you what you want.

Consider "…

- A widget can’t know and doesn’t decide its own position in the
  screen, since it’s the widget’s parent who decides the position of
  the widget.

  Since the parent’s size and position, in its turn, also depends on
  its own parent, it’s impossible to precisely define the size and
  position of any widget without taking into consideration the tree as
  a whole.

  If a child wants a different size from its parent and the parent
  doesn’t have enough information to align it, then the child’s size
  might be ignored.

Be specific when defining alignment.

"
from https://docs.flutter.dev/development/ui/layout/constraints

E.g.:

```
ListView(
  children: [
    Center(
      child: Card(
        child: Row(....
```

Comment: Yes it will solve by wrapping widget, Can you include the code-snippet?

Answer (score 1):

Try below code

```
 Container(
        height: 70,
        width: 250,
        child: Card(
          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(
              40,
            ),
          ),
          child: Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            children: [
              Icon(Icons.height),
              Icon(Icons.sort),
              SizedBox(
                width: 5,
              ),
              Text(
                'Sort',
              ),
              SizedBox(
                width: 24,
              ),
              Container(
                height: 30,
                color: Colors.black,
                width: 1,
              ),
              SizedBox(
                width: 24,
              ),
              Icon(Icons.filter_alt_outlined),
              SizedBox(
                width: 5,
              ),
              Text(
                'Filter',
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
```

Result-> [image]

Answer (score 1):

i would like to suggest a structure like this, using Spacer() will take the equal amount of available space on the both sides and using `const` will optimize and prevent it from rebuilding everytime the state changes.

```
Card(
    child : Row(
        children : [
            const Spacer(),
            YourCustomRow(),
            const Spacer(),
        ],  
    ),
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the card inside a Column widget.

```
Column(
 crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
 children: [
   //Put your card here
])
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code works fine. Probably your parent widget is not suitable for your case.

If you are using it in the ListView widget and you have a list to display it, you can try this:

```
Stack(
    children: [
      Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 38.0),
        child: ListView.builder(
            itemCount: 5,
            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
              return ListTile(
                  leading: const Icon(Icons.list),
                  title: Text("List item $index"));
            }),
      ),
      Align(
        alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
        child: Card(
          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(24.0),
          ),
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            child: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
              children: const [
                Icon(Icons.height),
                SizedBox(
                  width: 5,
                ),
                Text(
                  'Sort',
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  width: 24,
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 22,
                  child: VerticalDivider(
                    thickness: 1,
                    width: 2,
                    color: Colors.black,
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  width: 24,
                ),
                Icon(Icons.filter_alt_outlined),
                SizedBox(
                  width: 5,
                ),
                Text(
                  'Filter',
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ],
  ),
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> **Wrap your row with a Container and give width to that Container**

```
 Container(
                              width: 250,
                              child: Card(
                                child: Row(
                                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                                  children: [
                                    Icon(Icons.height),
                                    SizedBox(
                                      width: 5,
                                    ),
                                    Text(
                                      'Sort',
                                      style: ReediusCustomTheme.lable1
                                          .copyWith(color: ReediusCustomTheme.lableColor1),
                                    ),
                                    SizedBox(
                                      width: 24,
                                    ),
                                    Text(
                                      '|',
                                      style: ReediusCustomTheme.lable1
                                          .copyWith(color: ReediusCustomTheme.lableColor1),
                                    ),
                                    SizedBox(
                                      width: 24,
                                    ),
                                    Icon(Icons.filter_alt_outlined),
                                    SizedBox(
                                      width: 5,
                                    ),
                                    Text(
                                      'Filter',
                                      style: ReediusCustomTheme.lable1
                                          .copyWith(color: ReediusCustomTheme.lableColor1),
                                    ),
                                  ],
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
```